# Show that $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^n}$ for all $z \in U$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $U=\{z \in \Bbb{C}:0<|z|<1\}$,$n \in \Bbb{N}$. Show that if $f$ is holomorphic in $U$, $f(\frac{1}{5})=5^n$ and $|z^nf(z)|\geq 1$ for all $z\in U$, then $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^n}$, $\forall z\in U$

So I solved an excercise, using Cauchy inequalities, in which I proved that if $f$ is holomorphic in all $\Bbb{C}$, $R>0$ such that $|f(z)|<M|z|^n$ for all $z$ with $|z|>R$ then $f$ is a polynomial with degree $\leq n$. My intuition says this problem should be solved in a similar manner, however, since I've been trying now for a while, and I wasn't able to solve it, im starting to doubt about my intuition. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* Apply the the minimum modulus principle to $g(z)=z^n f(z)$.

Solution:

> $g$ is holomorphic in $U$ and never zero in $U$. Moreover, $g$ has a global minimum at $z=1/5$. By the minimum modulus principle, $g$ is constant.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f(z)$ in non-zero in $U$, since $|z^n f(z)|\geq 1$. Hence, $g:=1/f$ is holomorphic on $U$ and $|g(z)|\leq |z|^n$ for $z\in U$. Since $g$ is bounded around $0$, it must have a holomorphic extension, and in fact $g(0)=0$.

In fact, note that $|g(z)/z^{n-1}|\leq |z|$, which shows that $g(z)/z^{n-1}$ has a holomorphic extension to the whole unit disk, and maps $0$ to $0$. If you plug $z=1/5$, then you actually have equality, so Schwarz's lemma tells you that $g(z)/z^{n-1} =e^{i\theta}z$.

Again, by using $z=1/5$, you see that $g(z)=z^{n}$, as desired.